AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns' when I try to scale the dataset
def scale_dataset(dataframe, oversample=False):
  X = dataframe[dataframe.columns[:-1]].values
  y = dataframe[dataframe.columns[-1]].values

  scaler = StandardScaler()
  X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

  if oversample:
    ros = RandomOverSampler()
    X, y = ros.fit_resample(X, y)

  data = np.hstack((X, np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))))

  return data, X, y

train, X_train, y_train = scale_dataset(train, oversample=True)


Looks like that train in the input of the function is not a pd.DataFrame, but an np.ndarray
